# Flutter Admob Mediation Facebook Audience Does Not Showing

Tags: flutter, admob

I am trying to show Audience Network ad through my admob mediation. However, the only ad which showing are Admob, AppLovin and AdColony

The adapters have been installed in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.14.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.ads.mediation:applovin:11.9.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.8.0.2"
}
```

I also have set network_security_config.xml

```
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">dsimlife.com</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">id1.dsimlife.com</domain>
</domain-config>
```

I have no clue the mediation for audience network is not working. I have set everything fine. Anyway I am using Google Mobile Ads package from pub.dev

https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads

Does anyone can help me solving this problem? Been struggling a whole day without any progress for audience network.

Comment: In case you haven't seen it, https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/meta has instructions for setting up Meta. I recommend using [ad inspector](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/ad-inspector#advanced_ad_unit_debugging) and the single ad source test and bidding debugging features. If Ad Inspector is not finding signals for the meta ad source, check out the tips at https://developers.google.com/admob/android/troubleshoot-bidding

Comment: I have seen it, thats why I found "implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.14.0.0'" and also following all those steps. I will try ad inspector then. Hopefully, I can find something there